# Restrict access to all files and folders using password but allow access to one url with no password

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7, apache2

Goal - Restrict access to the server but allow access to

```
http://devserver/api/api-test
```

The below works fine to restrict users but I can't seem to give access rights to any user who wants to go to /api/api-test url in my .htaccess file.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
Require user pw

// the below does not work I have tried my variations.
<Files "api-test.php">
 Order Deny,Allow
 Allow from All
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "/api/api-test" ALLOWED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
Require user pw
Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=ALLOWED
```